# Weird NPE when retrieving Extras from Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, nullpointerexception, bundle

When I start my CalendarPopUp Activity, I get a `NullPointerException`.

Here's my code.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setUpWindow();
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras(); // This is Line 37
    boolean isForResult = extras.containsKey("result");
            //...
}
```

Here's the exception

```
07-30 09:33:47.269: E/AndroidRuntime(19979): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-30 09:33:47.269: E/AndroidRuntime(19979): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.moveinblue.planner/com.moveinblue.planner.utils.popup.CalendarPopup}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-30 09:33:47.269: E/AndroidRuntime(19979):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2079)
07-30 09:33:47.269: E/AndroidRuntime(19979):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2104)
07-30 09:33:47.269: E/AndroidRuntime(19979):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:132)
07-30 09:33:47.269: E/AndroidRuntime(19979):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1157)
07-30 09:33:47.269: E/AndroidRuntime(19979):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-30 09:33:47.269: E/AndroidRuntime(19979):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-30 09:33:47.269: E/AndroidRuntime(19979):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4575)
07-30 09:33:47.269: E/AndroidRuntime(19979):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-30 09:33:47.269: E/AndroidRuntime(19979):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-30 09:33:47.269: E/AndroidRuntime(19979):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
07-30 09:33:47.269: E/AndroidRuntime(19979):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
07-30 09:33:47.269: E/AndroidRuntime(19979):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-30 09:33:47.269: E/AndroidRuntime(19979): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-30 09:33:47.269: E/AndroidRuntime(19979):    at com.moveinblue.planner.utils.popup.CalendarPopup.onCreate(CalendarPopup.java:37)
07-30 09:33:47.269: E/AndroidRuntime(19979):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
07-30 09:33:47.269: E/AndroidRuntime(19979):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
07-30 09:33:47.269: E/AndroidRuntime(19979):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2033)
07-30 09:33:47.269: E/AndroidRuntime(19979):    ... 11 more
```

Can anybody help me here?

After debugging I know intent's mExtras object is null (intent is actually not null, but most of its inner objects are). Of course when calling `getExtras()` it returns null, and when calling `containsKey()` it will throw a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Post code how you start your activity.

Comment: It's called from almost 20 places in the app. The one that fails is a regular-extraless intent.

Comment: Than why don't you check `getExtras()` against `null`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `getExtras()` method returns null, if no extra has been added to the intent ([documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getExtras%28%29)). Try to add that `extra` to the intent first, then start the `CalendarPopUpActivity`, then extract this `Bundle` from the `Intent`.

### EDIT:

If you don't always need that extra, check it first like this

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setUpWindow();
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras(); // This is Line 37
    if (extras != null) {
        boolean isForResult = extras.containsKey("result");
        //...
    }
}
```

this way you will be able to detect if there is an extra in the intent, and you are saved from the `NullPointerException`

Comment: Yeah, but this popup window is called from a lot of places, and I don't always need to pass an extra to it.